# Decimal floating point literal syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, java

In java,

A decimal floating point literal(FPL) can be either a *Decimal FPL* or *Hexadecimal FPL*.

*Decimal FPL* consists of,  `<digits>.<digits><ExponentPart><f|F|d|D>`,
 where `<ExponentPart>` consists of `<e|E><+|-><digits>` (the sign is optional).

*Hexadecimal FPL* consists of, `<0x|0X><HexDigits><.><HexDigits><BinaryExponent><f|F|d|D>`, where `<BinaryExponent>` is, `<P|p><+|-><digits>` (sign is optional).

What is the FPL notation in javascript?

*Note: Beginner in JS*

Comment: [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript there is no formal type `floating-point number` there is only `Number` type. `Number` can have fraction or not.

From ecmascript 2015 [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals)

> DecimalLiteral ::
>
> DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits(opt) ExponentPart(opt)
>   . DecimalDigits ExponentPart(opt)
>   DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPart(opt)

Comment: did I mention FP number as type?